# Collection view cells are not displaying properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Designing tag like own collection view. Where user can search/select from tableview and upon selecting it will be added to collection view as you can see in attached image. but the problem is spacing and when there are only two cells in one row then first cell starting from left and second row is starting from right.

[image]

thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Please check collectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate, then used sizeItemAt method it solved your issue !!  Please check this video For CollectionViewFlowLayout :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HiX8SlEKnc Thank You :)